# Control Access for Invoking an API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an API gateway with a lot of resources defined. The authorization to access this API is AWS_IAM.

I want to create a user which can have permission to execute only two endpoints.

```
DELETE /a1/{id}/b1/{uid}

POST /c1/{id}
```

I have created one user with below permission but it doesn't work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke",
                "execute-api:ManageConnections"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:XXXXXXX/*/POST/c1/{id}",
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:XXXXXXX/*/DELETE/a1/{id}/b1/{uid}"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please help me to understand how to deal with these dynamic resource paths in policies?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to support dynamic paths, replace them with *

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke",
                "execute-api:ManageConnections"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:XXXXXXX/*/POST/c1/*",
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:XXXXXXX/*/DELETE/a1/*/b1/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```